# Generic data contract or specific data contract for an endpoint input on an API?

Tags: schema, endpoint, datacontract

Is it better to allow one generic class with properties that might not get used by the client, on a single endpoint in an API or specific types of classes with properties specific to the class on different endpoints ? E.g. A single Claim class data contract on a single endpoint or `ApplianceClaim` class on one endpoint and then `HouseholdClaim` class on another endpoint.

What would be best for maintenance?